# Attempting to Authorize AWS Lambda for Google Calendar API Call without OAuth Consent Screen

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am writing an Alexa Skill that will use the Google Calendar API to give me a custom response based on the contents of my Google Calendar. I am basically completed, except for one stumbling block. When I try to call the API from AWS Lambda, I get the following error:

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=235499230491-5nkukk98kfnt16fvtmm2acrgq4r4ucr2.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&access_type=offline&response_type=code

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this application with the command-line parameter

--noauth_local_webserver
```

I was wondering if there could be any way that I could authenticate this AWS instance to accept my Google Calendar API. Any thoughts, StackOverflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Google Service Accounts.

These are for server to server applications.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount